# VSTS + Docker Swarm: continuous deployment under private network

Tags: linux, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, docker-swarm, private-network

I'm setting up a CI/CD with Visual Studio Team Services based on Docker Swarm.

The target machine I'm deploying to is under private network.

Because of that, the target machine is not reachable from VSTS so I can not use ssh or any kind of webhook to initiate the deployment.

To solve this, I'm thinking to run some service on the target machine to periodically check if any new images are pushed to the registry.

Is there any service that covers this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to setup a private agent on an machine that can access to the target machine (can be setup on that target machine), after that just do build or release with this private agent.

In other words, the target machine just need to be accessible from the agent machine.

[Deploy an agent on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-linux)